# Universalchardet is unable to read text file

Tags: java, character-encoding

I try to use `juniversalchardet` to read a text file.

```
FileReader     in     = new FileReader(my_file);
java.io.Reader reader = null;
BufferedReader br     = new BufferedReader(in);

try {
    reader = ReaderFactory.createBufferedReader(my_file);

    while ((line = ((BufferedReader)reader).readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

I get error message:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector.detectCharset(Ljava/io/File;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: This is probably because you are using a combination of incompatible libraries, or you are compiling your code with version A of a library but running it with version B. Make sure you use the correct combination of versions (check the library's documentation about what's needed).

Comment: @Jesper : I use sample from this site: https://github.com/albfernandez/juniversalchardet
I use version 2.1.0.